# Append R dataframe to MySQL table

Tags: mysql, r, append

Im trying to append a dataframe I have manipulated in R to a simple MySQL database with an existing table (table_a) with four columns as follows:

**id**. Primary key and auto incrementing.
**name**. varchar(45).
**value_a**. varchar(45).
**value_b**. varchar(45).

The dataframe (data) has three columns.
name.
value_a.
value_b.

I can connect to the database OK using RMySQL and dbConnect. But when I use the **dbWriteTable** command to append the dataframe "**data**" I get the following error.

***Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) :

could not run statement: Unknown column 'row_names' in 'field list'***

I know it connects ok because i can get it to create a new table but i want to continually append to an existing one in MySQL.

Any ideas anyone.

```
con <- dbConnect(MySQL(),
                 user = 'root',
                 password = '???????',
                 host = 'localhost',
                 dbname='rdbtest')
dbWriteTable(conn = con, name = 'table_a', value = data, append = TRUE, header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok solved.. needed to add row.names=FALSE

```
con <- dbConnect(MySQL(),
                 user = 'root',
                 password = '???????',
                 host = 'localhost',
                 dbname='rdbtest')
dbWriteTable(conn = con, name = 'table_a', value = data, append = TRUE, header = TRUE, row.names = FALSE)
```